# Select specific range of elements in Combination vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, combinations, mesh, matlab-deployment

I am creating a mesh grid or combination vector of an array. The full combination vector is so large that MATLAB prompts me "out of memory" error. I have written a code to create the mesh grid, depending on the variable "Col".

```
Col=9;
numMatrix = uint8([1 2 3]);
meshString=strcat("a3 = combvec(" ,repmat('numMatrix ,', 1, Col-1), "numMat )")
eval(meshString);
```

If the Col value is 9, then the size of the matrix formed is this.

```
Variable              Size               Byte
 a3                   9x19683            1417176  double
```

The problem with this code is that if my Col value is 25, then the size of a3 will be 25x3^25 which require the RAM of 25*3^25*8/1024/1024/1024 GB (1.5782e+05 GB) which is not realizable. So I want to create a specific range of combinations. For example, to have only the first 50000 combinations directly then after the processing goes for the next 50000.

P.S: I have also used the function [b1,b2....,b25]=ndgrid(1:3) to create the b's grids and then flattening them to form the combination. It also suffers from the same problem explained above.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Also you should avoid to use `eval`. So instead of using `combvec(x,x,x,x,x,...,x,y)` you can use `x = repmat({x},Col,1)` and then `combvec(x{:},y)` this is way cleaner.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to bruteforce a problem, maybe there is a mathematical tricks that can help you to solve your problem more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `combvec` is totally predictable so instead of generating the whole vector you could simply compute each iteration individually.

Let's take a simple example:

```
% we compute combvec(1:3,1:3,1:3,1:3)
n = 4;
x = 1:3;
x = repmat({x},n,1)
y = combvec(x{:})
```

Here `y` is a `4x81` matrix. And we noticed that sinced we only use combination of the vector `[1,2,3]` then the `j-th` column will correspond to `j-1` in base 3.

So we can write a small function that will convert a decimal number in base 3:

```
function r = f(j,n)
    r = fliplr(dec2base(j-1,3,n)-47).' % small tricks with -47 to implicitely convert a char to its ascii value minus 47.
end
```

And now we can verify the equality, for example with j=10:

```
all(f(10,n) == y(:,10))
```

And we indeed got: `True` as a result.

It will also works for multiple value:

```
all(f(9:10,n) == y(:,9:10))
```

So you just need to add the last row of combvec and now you can split your operation and let run your computer for a week.